# Title over a group of subplots

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want a figure with six plots inside; I split it with subplots. For example

```
for i = 1:12
    subplot(3,4,i)
    plot(peaks)
    title(['Title plot ',num2str(i)])
end
```

I would like to add two global titles, let's say a global title for the six plots on the left hand side and another title for the six other plots on the right hand side.

[image]

I don't have `2018b` version, so I cannot use `sgtitle('Subplot Title');`. Is it possible use `suptitle('my title');` somehow?
I can use `text()` but resizing the window, the two labels move.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's 12 correct. Six per side

Comment: I splited the figure in a 3x4 subfigures to have 3 row and 4 columns. It doesn't matter the distribution for the question, anyway

Comment: I added an image. Now should be clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`annotation`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) for that, with the location of subplots 1 and 3:

```
for k = 1:12
    sp(k) = subplot(3,4,k);
    plot(peaks)
    title(['Title plot ',num2str(k)])
end
spPos = cat(1,sp([1 3]).Position);
titleSettings = {'HorizontalAlignment','center','EdgeColor','none','FontSize',18};
annotation('textbox','Position',[spPos(1,1:2) 0.3 0.3],'String','Left title',titleSettings{:})
annotation('textbox','Position',[spPos(2,1:2) 0.3 0.3],'String','Right title',titleSettings{:})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I did not test this, but you can get the handle to a subplot object and then perform the title method on this handle. I would also suggest to then apply the title after the loop.

**CODE**

```
for k = 1:12
    h(k) = subplot(3, 4, i)
    plot(peak)
end

title(h(1), 'Left side')
title(h(8), 'Right side')   % find out the right index yourself
```

---

*Remark:*

Do not use `i` or `j` as iteration variable for they are already defined in the namespace of MATLAB as imaginary unit.

Comment: This works nicely after making some dirty tweaks like e.g. breaking empty lines with cells to gain spaces or buffering spaces: title(h(x), {'title',''},'HorizontalAlignment', 'center')